# linebreak or new line in the text field of a label in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, html, newline, line-breaks

How can I have line break in text of a label in ASP.net. 
is there a way in HTML 5 to resolve this issue

Comment: Have you tried using two seperate labels?

Comment: What is wrong with <br/>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be achieved thru

```
<br />

<asp:Label ID="lblAdmin"  Visible='<%# IsAdmin %>' Font-Names="Time News Roman !important;"     runat="server" style="text-align: left"><br/>(Admin)</asp:Label>
```

it works perfectly as  desired