# How to insert a character return on an asp element

Tags: html, asp.net, return, newline

I have the following line

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCAPTCHAWrong" runat="server" Text=" Please check your answer." Style="color: red; display: none;"></asp:Label>
```

And the output is

Please check your answer.

How can I change this so each word is on a new line but all within the same asp element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linebreak or new line in the text field of a label in ASP.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604086/linebreak-or-new-line-in-the-text-field-of-a-label-in-asp-net)

Comment: I don't think the linked question answers OP's question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use CSS and create a style for it:

```
.WordBreak {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: This worked but I also had to set a width size, thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can try populating the label value from code-behind such as

```
lblCAPTCHAWrong.Text = string.Format("Please{0}check{1}your{2}answer.", "<br/>","<br/>","<br/>");
```

Comment: What if the text for label is dynamic? This ain't a solution just a patch.

Comment: If the text is dynamic, then you can use Regex  & dynamically insert the break tokens in the place of blank space.

Comment: http://regexr.com/3bvel - Regex to make groups of blank space. Or use String.Replace to replace blank with break tokens

Comment: Yes, exactly therefore you should include the same in your answer. It will improve the quality of your answer.